# Why Qsynth and Fluidsynth sounds different?

Tags: linux, midi

Qsynth is a GUI for fluidsynth.

Why sound is different when I play the same MIDI file with the same soundfont using fluidsynth command line tool and the GUI?

```
fluidsynth -ni soundfont.sf2 music.mid -F /tmp/q.wav
qsynth  soundfont.sf2 music.mid
```